# Как уменьшить расстояние между элементами в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как уменьшить расстояние между элементами в строке?

То есть, заменить несколько пробелов одним, например:

```
'I am    good       boy'
```

Как мне сделать так:

```
'I am good boy'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Торопитесь принимать ответы

```
' '.join(i for i in 'I am    good       boy'.split(' ') if i != '')
```

Comment: Можно упростить, чтобы произвольные пробельные символы (включая '\n') на один пробел заменить: `s = ' '.join(s.split())`

Answer (score 5):

Используя регулярные выражения:

```
In [1]: s = 'I am    good       boy'

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)
Out[3]: 'I am good boy'
```